# Got a SIGABRT while executing native code xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, sigabrt

I've built a xamarin.ios app. The app has been working absolutely fine. There have been no code changes and out of the blue, the app now crashes when accessing the camera. I have no idea why this is happening, could anyone shed some light on this problem? I've google around this error and tried various things, including removing various packages. I recently updated to ios 10 but the app was still working fine after the update. The error is below:

> 2016-10-10 21:44:28.925 Coacher[307:24128] critical:  Native
>   stacktrace:
>
> 2016-10-10 21:44:28.934 Coacher[307:24128] critical:  0
>   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00363d33
>   mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 242 2016-10-10 21:44:28.934
>   Coacher[307:24128] critical:  1   libsystem_platform.dylib
>   0x1db5326d _sigtramp + 24 2016-10-10 21:44:28.935 Coacher[307:24128]
>   critical:     2   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1da9fd8f
>    + 64 2016-10-10 21:44:28.935 Coacher[307:24128] critical:
>     3   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x1da9fdd9
>   system_set_sfi_window + 0 2016-10-10 21:44:28.935 Coacher[307:24128]
>   critical:     4   TCC                                 0x201a8e85
>    + 228 2016-10-10 21:44:28.936 Coacher[307:24128] critical:
>     5   TCC                                 0x201a8da1  + 0
>   2016-10-10 21:44:28.936 Coacher[307:24128] critical:  6   TCC
>   0x201ab57b  + 276 2016-10-10 21:44:28.936 Coacher[307:24128]
>   critical:     7   libxpc.dylib                        0x1db8915f
>    + 46 2016-10-10 21:44:28.937 Coacher[307:24128] critical:
>     8   libxpc.dylib                        0x1db89101  + 26
>   2016-10-10 21:44:28.937 Coacher[307:24128] critical:  9
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x1d9ae49b  + 604
>   2016-10-10 21:44:28.937 Coacher[307:24128] critical:  10 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x1d9afa91  + 378
>   2016-10-10 21:44:28.938 Coacher[307:24128] critical:  11 
>   libdispatch.dylib                   0x1d9af8b7  + 106
>   2016-10-10 21:44:28.938 Coacher[307:24128] critical:  12 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x1db55947 _pthread_wqthread +
>   1168 2016-10-10 21:44:28.938 Coacher[307:24128] critical:     13 
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x1db5549c start_wqthread + 8
>   2016-10-10 21:44:28.939 Coacher[307:24128] critical: 
>   ================================================================= Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
>   error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
>
> ## application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because of your iOS 10 update. You need to request the permission for the camera now. The following blog post explains how to set up these permissions, now.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/new-ios-10-privacy-permission-settings/

> Starting in iOS 10, nearly all APIs that require requesting authorization and other APIs, such as opening the camera or photo gallery, require a new key value pair to describe their usage in the Info.plist. This is very similar to the requirement for NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to be put into the Info.plit when using Geolocation and iBeacon APIs. The difference now is that the application will crash when the app attempts authorization without these keys set.

Comment: Wow thanks so much!!!! You really saved my bacon. I had no idea I had to do this, the error was unclear what the issue was. Thanks!!!

Comment: I still have an issue here, I want to record videos with audio, so I have added both NSCameraUsageDescription and NSMicrophoneUsageDescription. The app request access to the camera and then crashes, if I reopen the app it then asks for audio access and works. How do I request both permissions?

Comment: Hmm not sure maybe request the microphone first and then start the camera? Without code it's hard to say now.I'd have to play around and search the docs, too. Maybe add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`, too. Sorry I haven't used it yet in production.

Comment: No worries Sven-Michael Stube, problem now solved. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you please write what you have done to solve your problem? So others will know what to do, if they have the same problem.

Comment: So I based the code of this https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/AVCam/ this worked fine but after the update to iOS10 stopped working. After I requested the information in the info.plist it started working again, but crashed on first load. Instead of figuring out why I just used the updated version of the AVCam example which can be found here.   https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios10/AVCam/ I suspect the problem was the order of asking permission in the code